# magento redirectReferer redirecting with urlencode

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog

Am using `$this->_redirectReferer();` to redirect back to category page.
when i use some params, my url is like
`electronics.html?color=24&manufacturer=117&price=-1000`
then the redirected url is like
`electronics.html?color=24&am;manufacturer=117&am;price=-1000`
my url is encoded. all the & is changed to {&amp};
how can i avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirectReferer` calls `_getRefererUrl` from the same class that contains this line:

```
$refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($refererUrl);
```

The escape url is basically `htmlspecialchars()`.

You shouldn't change the `_getRefererUrl` method because it's risky, but you can write your own method similar with the `_redirectReferer` where you undo the htmlspecial chars and use that method:

Something like this:

```
protected function _redirectRefererNoSpecialChars($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    $refererUrl = htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);//this needs to be added
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Mind that since 1.9.4.1, you probably want to use these updated flags: `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5 | ENT_HTML401`