# "&amp;" instead of "&" in language switch url

Tags: magento-1.7, language, switcher

when using magento's language switcher, the generated URL is:

```
a href="http://www.shop.com/index.php/bags/eastpak.html?___store=en&amp;___from_store=default">
```

Magento version 1.7 is used.

How can I convert this `&amp;` to &?

Is Magento's Redirect class reason for this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be correct. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying, especially in product list pages, when url contains all search params.

To avoid this, some changes are required in two files :

1)  in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`

under

```
protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

add

```
protected function _redirectRefererNoSpecialChars($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    $refererUrl = htmlspecialchars_decode($refererUrl, ENT_NOQUOTES);//this needs to be added

    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

2)  in `Mage_Directory_CurrencyController`

change `$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getBaseUrl());`

with `$this->_redirectRefererNoSpecialChars(Mage::getBaseUrl());`

[Thanks Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/56427/24398)